# Работа с пользовательскими папками в C#

Tags: c#, windows, .net

Коллеги, добрый день.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как программно в C# получить доступ к пользовательским папкам в Windows? Например:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Opera\Opera";
```

Таке же, как программно определить версию оси.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.aspx)**

- [OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx)
- [UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.username.aspx)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло! :)